# How can I use objects in foreach loop and replace variables (OOP)?

Tags: php, loops, oop, object

This code...

```
 foreach ($classes->fieldMappings as $fieldMapping) {
        echo $fieldMapping['fieldName'];
 }
```

... is giving me the following output:

```
id
username
password
email
isActive
```

What I want to do now is, I want to put this code...

```
$entity->setUsername($data['form[username]']);
$entity->setEmail($data['form[email]']);
$entity->setPassword($data['form[password]']);
$entity->setIsActive($data['form[isActive]']);
```

...into a loop. So I replaced it like this:

```
foreach ($classes->fieldMappings as $fieldMapping) { 
   $entity->set'.$fieldMapping['fieldName'].'($data['form['.$fieldMapping['fieldName'].']']);
}
```

I get a Parse Error, but I actually don't know how to write this in the right way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in one line, see the **Complex (curly) syntax** at [PHP: Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

```
$entity->{'set'.$fieldMapping['fieldName']}($data['form['.$fieldMapping['fieldName'].']']);
```

However it might be more readable as:

```
$func = 'set'.$fieldMapping['fieldName'];
$args = $data['form['.$fieldMapping['fieldName'].']'];
$entity->$func($args);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your method name into curly braces, so making it like:

```
 $entity->{'set'.$fieldMapping['fieldName']}(...)
```